# Minimize $\quad z=4\left(x_{1}-1\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-2\right)^{2}$ s.t $\quad x_{1}+x_{2} \leq 2 \ ,x_{1}, x_{2} \geq-1$ without KKT conditions

Tags: inequality, optimization

The problem is to minimize $\quad z=4\left(x_{1}-1\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-2\right)^{2}$
Subject to the following constraints.
$$\quad x_{1}+x_{2} \leq 2$$$$ x_{1}, x_{2} \geq-1$$
I don't want to solve this problem with the KKT conditions. I am looking for a more intuitive way, maybe using geometry or inequalities. a simple approach but I can't seem to think of anything outside KKT which **I can't use**.

Any suggestions??

Comment: I am not sure but may help you,https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xa3ctox2ch

Comment: Thanks but I would like to go for an analytical approach. Not just using a software

Comment: What is "KKT" ?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ubiquitous Lagrange multipliers with the help of some slack variables to handle the inequalities.

Calling

$$
\cases{
f(x_1,x_2)=4\left(x_{1}-1\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-2\right)^{2}\\
g_1(x_1,x_2) = 2- x_{1}-x_{2}\\
g_2(x_1,x_2) = x_{1} + 1\\
g_3(x_1,x_2) = x_{2} + 1
}
$$

you can formulate

$$
L(x_1,x_2,\lambda,s) = f(x_1,x_2)+\sum_{k=1}^3\lambda_k(g_k(x_1,x_2)-s_k^2)
$$

The stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 8 (x_1-1) -\lambda_1+\lambda_2\\
 2 (x_2-2)-\lambda_1+\lambda_3 \\
 -x_1-x_2+2 -s_1^2\\
 x_1+1 -s_2^2\\
 x_2+1-s_3^2 \\
 \lambda_1 s_1\\
 \lambda_2 s_2 \\
 \lambda_3 s_3 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Pay attention to the complementary relations $\lambda_ks_k = 0$. They simplify a lot the calculations.
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
f& x_1 & x_2 & \lambda_1 &\lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & s_1^2&s_2^2& s_3^2\\
 \frac{4}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{6}{5} & -\frac{8}{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{9}{5} & \frac{11}{5} \\
 9 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
 16 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\
 17 & -1 & 3 & 2 & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 25 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 16 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 25 & 3 & -1 & 16 & 0 & 22 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Here $s_k = 0$ indicates that the corresponding restriction is active.

Follows a level curve plot showing in red the stationary points. Finally follows the point qualification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y=2-x$ in $4 (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2$.

You get $x^2+4 (x-1)^2$ which is minimum for $x=\frac45$ so we have $y=\frac65$ and
$z_{min}=\frac{4}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

Make a figure!

The feasible domain $\Omega$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $h$ connecting the points $(-1,3)$ and $(3,-1)$. The objective function is $f(x_1,x_2):=4(x_1-1)^2+(x_2-2)^2$. Its level lines are ellipses centered at the point $(1,2)$ slightly above $h$. It is then obvious that the smallest ellipse intersecting $\Omega$ is the ellipse touching $h$ at some point. It follows that we have to find the point on $h$ having smallest value of $f$.

To this end we parametrize $h$ by
$$h:\qquad t\mapsto\bigl(x_1(t),x_2(t)\bigr):=(t,2-t)\quad(-1\leq t\leq 3)\ ,$$
and consider the pullback of $f$ to $h$:
$$\phi(t):=f\bigl(x_1(t),x_2(t)\bigr)=4(t-1)^2+\bigl((2-t)-2\bigr)^2=5t^2-8t+4\ .$$
The minimum is taken at $t={4\over5}\in[-1,3]$ and leads to the minimum value $z_*=f\bigl({4\over5},{6\over5}\bigr)={4\over5}$.